# Many Statement in the same transaction PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transactions, toad

How can i make many statement in the same transaction :

```
update .....;--s1
update .....;--s2
update .....;--s3
COMMIT;
```

if an error occur in s2 rollback s1, if an error occur in s3 rollback s2 and s1;

Comment: You must use `anonymous block` with `EXCEPTION` Handling

Comment: If you are using `sqlplus` use `whenever sqlerror rollback` at the beginning of the script

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No i use Toad for oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exception handling like this:

```
BEGIN
  update .....;--s1
  update .....;--s2
  update .....;--s3
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: Invalid syntax. See the answer of @sylvainleroux instead.

Comment: @user272735 I have fixed the syntax, I cannot delete the answer as it was accepted.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the correct syntax in PL/SQL to rollback in case of exception is:

```
begin
  -- stmt1
  -- stmt2
  -- stmt3
  commit;
exception
  when others then -- <--
    rollback;
end;
```

<sup>BTW there isn't such thing as `AUTOCOMMIT` in PL/SQL. This is a SQL*Plus command.</sup>

Comment: This is the correct answer despite the votes and what OP has marked to be correct.